# e2fsck taking a long time

Tags: external-hdd, disk, fsck

I have a portable 2TB drive, used over USB 2,  that's giving trouble and I am running

> e2fsck -f -y -v /dev/sdb1

to attempt to fix it.

But it's been running for 12 hours and gives no indication if it's actually doing anything (I'm running it out of gparted, so all I'm seeing is the "cylon" bar bouncing to-and-fro)

Should it really be taking this long?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably yes; I've done the same, if you run fsck over USB it can take all day + for a big drive.
Leave it running, or else dismantle it & use a SATA link - it will be much faster in the end!